# can't access samba files from specific pc

Tags: 18.04, samba, windows-10

I have an ubuntu server 18.04 setup for file share.
I created the designated files to be shared per user and all works fine, except for one Windows 10 Home PC which cannot access the files on the server.

When connecting, it requests the user credentials, which is correctly inserted, but  errors in "Username and password incorrect". Regardless of the username and password I enter, I get the same error.

Connecting to a different server (Windows & same username and password), access is granted.

When I use the above username and password from a different windows pc, connecting to the same ubuntu server, access is granted.

So only when I try to access the ubuntu server from this pc, I receive the error.

I deleted and recreated the user account, passwords, file share permissions on folders and samba level permission control, I even created new folders for new file share setup.

Oh, this account had previous access to the server.

If you could please assist.
Looking forward to your reply and assistance,

Thanks.

Comment: I have a similar problem, regularly leading to a `Samba panic or segfault´.  I filed a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1821935) for that. Maybe your problem is similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more a Windows 10 issue, than a Ubuntu Issue.

It could be configured, that Samba is using the protocol `SMB` in the version `1.x`, but Microsoft knows it is insecure (see things like 'Eternal Blue') and does not support it by default ... But you are able to activate it:
http://wdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/20736/~/how-to-enable-smb-1.0%2Fcifs-file-sharing-support-on-windows-10

Samba should be able to to negotiate the protocol, so if v1 is not available, it should switch to v2 or v3.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91939/discussion-on-answer-by-lupuse-cant-access-samba-files-from-specific-pc).